# PHP 7 Multidimensional Array Initialization

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wrote these PHP scripts maybe 10 years ago, most likely on PHP 4, but maybe on 3.
I worked on them a couple years ago and got them to work on PHP 5, but now my host has upgraded to PHP 7, and I am throwing undefined offset errors by the hundreds if not thousands.  I was under the impression that if I try to load a value into an undefined array, that it would create the index, but apparently not.  So my solution is to simply create the empty array to avoid this.  I am just trying to determine if nested loops are the only solution.  We are a preschool, and for my first script, my arrays are things like:

$childs_classroom[classroom][week][day_of_week]

classroom is 0-4, weeks 0-260, and dow 0-4

When I try to increment an array like this, it creates an undefined offset error every time (I believe).  Is there a simpler way other than nested loops to create this array and fill it with nulls/zeroes so I don't get errors? I apologize if this is basic stuff, I've forgotten more about PHP than I remember atm.

Comment: You need a reproducible example, this `$childs_classroom[1][2][3] = 'test';` has always worked.

Comment: I am beginning to realize that when I was using PHP 4, there was no need to initialize or define variables.  In later versions, this looks like it became a requirment. I am seeing now after scaling down the error log that it starts by throwing an undefined variable error, then appears to throw undefined index errors for every use.  So I guess I am now asking, how would I pre-define this $childs_classroom variable?

Comment: Three examples the first two work the third doesn't work because those are constants that haven't been defined. https://3v4l.org/QjCAD You need to provide an example that does NOT work.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I see some great ideas.  I am on my way out the door for a 3-week trip to Turkey and Greece.  I will pick this back up when I return.

Answer (score 0):

Nested arrays are indeed automatically created (with no notice error) if you assign them, but since you say *incrementing*, it sounds as though you are accessing the value prior to initialization. Incrementing a non-existent variable or key with `$var++` will cause warnings, as it is equal to `$var = $var + 1`, and the right-hand side is evaluated before the variable exists.

This can be avoided by setting the key to zero first.

In PHP7, an easy way to do this is to use `$var ??= 0`. This will initialize `$var` to `0` if it does not contain a non-zero value yet, but will not overwrite an existing non-zero value.

For example, the following code will initialize an array key, then increment it twice, without emitting e_notice warnings.

```
$non_existent_array['non_existent']['key'] ??= 0;
$non_existent_array['non_existent']['key']++;

var_dump($non_existent_array);

$non_existent_array['non_existent']['key'] ??= 0;
$non_existent_array['non_existent']['key']++;

var_dump($non_existent_array);



array(1) {
  ["non_existent"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["key"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["non_existent"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["key"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass warnings with null coalescing operator (??) in PHP7. Example:

```
echo $childs_classroom[classroom][week][day_of_week] ?? "N/A"
```

will print the value if exists, or N/A

Comment: _Warning: Use of undefined constant classroom - assumed 'classroom' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
Warning: Use of undefined constant week - assumed 'week' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
Warning: Use of undefined constant day_of_week - assumed 'day_of_week' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)_

Comment: Supposed that you defined them in your code.. It is just taken from the question... If they are variables from a user, or database, or a loop, for example; you may use echo $childs_classroom[$classroom][$week][$day_of_week] ?? "N/A"